# I have done "brew install postgresql" got 9.0.2 but running "gem install pg" I get missing library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

```
gem install pg
```

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   checking for pg_config... yes
>   Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
>   checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
>   checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
>   checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
>   checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
>   checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
>   Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: This worked!        env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you either need to specify your postgres lib directory:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=/path/to/pg_dir
```

or perhaps a 32bit vs.64 bit compatibility problem

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install pg
```

Answer (score 0):

"env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg" worked for me when using Snow Leopard.